# Karma + angular-mocks TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'angular.mock = {}')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to write unit tests using Karma + Jasmine, but running into an error with angular-mocks. When running grunt test I get the following error:

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) ERROR
>    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'angular.mock = {}')
>    at /Users/danielbogart/Documents/coding/work/AexNav/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular->mocks.js:17
>   Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.4) ERROR
>    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mock' of undefined
>    at /Users/danielbogart/Documents/coding/work/AexNav/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular->mocks.js:17

Gruntfile karma config:

```
    karma: {
        options: {
            frameworks: ['jasmine'],
            files: [ 
                'dom_munger.data.appjs',
                'tests/spec/*.js',
                'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
            ],
            logLevel: 'ERROR',
            reporters: ['mocha'],
            autoWatch: false, //watching is handled by grunt-contrib-watch
            singleRun: true
        },
        all_tests: {
            browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome']
        },
        during_watch: {
            browsers: ['PhantomJS']
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to include angular.js as well, then only angular.mocks will work else window.angular will be undefined.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need to include angular.js as well, then only angular.mocks will work else window.angular will be undefined.

```
 files: [ 
            'dom_munger.data.appjs',
            'path/to/angular.js', //<-- include angularjs
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'tests/spec/*.js'
        ],
```

Comment: I stumbled around this as well. If you're using browserify make sure you require your bundle before you require angular-mocks.

Comment: It was a missing reference file in "files" in the karma configuration file for me.

Answer (score 4):

**update for 2017 and webpack 2** (but same angular<2)

1. like @jlew said, angular-mocks expects angular on the window
2. module reference is being replaces by webpack

So in tests you need an header like:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks/ngMock';
```

and replace each global `module` reference with `angular.mock.module`

Comment: almost worked here on my setup, for me webpack says that module "angular" has no default export. I solved using like:

`import * as angular from "angular";` `import "angular-mocks/ngMock";`

Answer (score 3):

angular-mocks.js presumes that angular.js has been included as well.

Comment: I guess what jlew meant is that the angular.js needs to be included before the angular-mocks.js is included like:     files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on the following statement :

`angular.mock.module( 'ui.router' )`

This was caused by a wrong order in libraries declaration :

**karma.config.js :**

```
...
files: ['./node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js']
   .concat(dependencies),
...
```

(`dependencies` was the list of my libs and containing `angular.js`)

I simply move `'./node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'` into the dependencies list, but **AFTER** `angular.js` :

Like this :

```
...
'./node_modules/angular/angular.js',
'./node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
...
```

---

To go further :

If you look at `angular-mocks.js` you can see it needs `angular.js` to work !

```
/**
 * @license AngularJS v1.7.5
 * (c) 2010-2018 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 * License: MIT
 */
(function(window, angular) {

'use strict';

/* global routeToRegExp: true */
...
```